# If I accidentally delete an address with funds

Tags: address, private-key, public-key

If the address is deleted (while using an online provider like CoinJar), does that mean the coins are lost for good?

Or all public/private keys are still held by the company and the address deleted (and coins) can be recovered?

Would the securing of public and private keys be treated the same by most online wallet service providers?

Comment: You'd have to ask the wallet provider about their backup, retention, and recovery policies. To be conservative, you should assume that if you delete a key, you will never get it back, but a malicious person still could.